# Wi-Fi Direct between android and Linux

Tags: android, c, linux, wifi-direct

I have a little problem to connect a linux with Android using [Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct). 

 
On my Linux : I use :

```
p2p_find
p2p_peers
p2p_prov_disc <ANDROID:MAC> keypad
```

I got the response :
`P2P-PROV-DISC-SHOW-PIN 96:35:0a:d5:83:e8 44779443`

On Android I use this code :

```
bsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Click Connection :");
            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            if (peers.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("No peers found , MAC test : 00:e0:4c:61:0f:d0");
                config.deviceAddress = "00:e0:4c:61:0f:d0";
            }
            else 
            {
                WifiP2pDevice device = (WifiP2pDevice) peers.get(0);
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                System.out.println("Connection to: " + config.deviceAddress);
            }
            config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.DISPLAY;
            config.wps.pin = pin.getText().toString();
            config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
            mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    System.out.println("Connection Suceess");
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connect failed. Retry.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("Connection failed");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

On my Logcat I got :

```
Click Connection :
code :44779443
Connection to: 00:e0:4c:61:0f:d0
2
Connection failed
```

ifconfig on my Linux :`HWaddr 00:e0:4c:61:0f:d0`

I am new with Android, I don't know if can't print a "errno" coresponding to my failure code. And I dont see in the class [WifiP2pManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html) an interface for a callback function failure connection.

Edit: I also tried `config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.KEYPAD;` and I think it's more accurate.

Edit:I'm stupid, that worked fine, it's just i push twice the connect button (yeah I thought I mistaken somewhere with event managament).
So i used PBC method now :

```
config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
```

After that I created a Socket :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 4242);
        if (socket.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Connection ok");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("connection failed");
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
             System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}).start();
```

But I got :`java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.1 (port 4242): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)`
Why on my c program basically i made :

```
-> connection to wpa_supplicant using wpa_ctrl.c
-> PING REQUEST to wpa_supplicant, reponse : PONG
-> P2p find
-> socket, bind , listen... No error return
-> p2p peer FIRST ( i dont manage all device for now)
-> p2p_prov_disc MAC::address pbc
-> using Select for checking Connection for accept
```

If I got a connection Success why I got Network unreachable?
And when I click to connect I go in the callack function OnpeersAvailable and no in OnConnectionInfoAvailable...